# Is it possible to change the client a socks proxy is connected to?

Tags: proxy, socks-proxy, socks5

I want to connect to 2 socks5 proxies and connect to google.com.

If I create a tcp socket and connect it to proxy1 tell it to connect to proxy2 and tell proxy2 to connect to google.com:80 I have essentially created a chain that goes

me > proxy1 > proxy2 > google.com:80

If I want to visit amazon.com, can I somehow tell proxy2 to drop the connection to google.com and create a new one to amazon.com without closing the socket and droping the connection I have with proxy1?

Reading through the RFC I didn't find any mention of such functionality and as far as I'm concerned the socks proxy doesn't even interpret the data I am sending through it. That leads me to suspect that it is not possible but It's hard to imagine that modern browsers (mostly all) that support socks5 proxing drop the connection every time you go to a different website, because that seems horribly slow to be reconnecting to proxies every time you change destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,

The socks5 standard states that for each connection you'll create a new bind request (and so issue a new request to the proxy server) for each attempt. So, for two different websites, you're always going to have to create new connections each time.

Yes it's slow, but there's little reason to be running two proxies like this, so it's hardly a priority.